# Reductions among two problems related to walks of length $k$

Tags: graphs, reductions

Consider the following two problems:

A. Given a directed graph and a parameter $k$, determine if it contains a path (not necessarily simple) of length $k$.

B. Given a directed graph, two vertices $s,t$ and a parameter $k$, determine if the graph contains a path from $s$ to $t$ (not necessarily simple) of length $k$.

How can I reduce problem B to problem A?

I know that I can make a DFS tree at height $k$ with repeating vertices, however it solves the problem directly rather than by reduction.

Comment: What kind of reduction are you looking for?

Comment: k is a constant, and I need to convert graph G  to G' s.t by giving a solution to A I can find a solution to B by run the algorithm on G'

Comment: Are you sure you're not interested in a reduction in the other direction?

Comment: I'm sure. The opposite it's much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $k$ is a constant you can solve $B$ in polynomial-time by exploring all $O(n^{k-1})$ paths of length $k$ starting from $s$ and ending in $t$, as you point out.

At this point the reduction is trivial:
If the answer to an instance $\langle G, s, t\rangle$ of $B$ is "yes" then the corresponding instance of $A$ is $G$.
If the answer to the instance  $\langle G, s, t \rangle$  is "no", then the instance of $A$ is the empty graph.

Comment: The problem that is directe solution and  I need reduction  I starting to believe that there's is typo at the assignment. thank you anyway

Comment: Formally, this is a reduction...

Comment: This "solve-it-up-front" reduction is legitimate because $k$ is not part of the input, so $O(n^{k-1})$ is polynomial in $n$ (and you're allowed to spend that much time converting the problem instance from $B$ to $A$). If you want a reduction that allows $k$ to be part of the input, I can't see one. Problem $A$ gives you very little flexibility: For a digraph containing a cycle, the answer is YES for every $k$. If you restrict inputs to DAGs, then assuming $k \le n$, a reduction that attaches an $n$-path before $s$, and another $n$-path after $t$, and increases $k$ by $2n$, would work.

Comment: If $k$ is part of the input and is polynomially bounded w.r.t. the size of $G$ then you can reduce $B$ to $A$. A rough sketch of the idea is to create $k$ "layers" where the first layer contains only $s$, the last layer contains only $t$, and the intermediate $k-2$ layers are copies of $G$. The edge edges of $G$ are rewirted to only go from one layer to the next.

Comment: Ah of course, making a nice DAG out of copies! I was thinking too narrowly. I think this is probably the solution the question was looking for -- and perhaps OP wrote "k is a constant" without that actually being in the question, and without realising the implications.